# Why I can't init static members

Tags: c++, android-ndk, static-members

I have a class `MotionDirection` with static members. The source code of the class is below. But I just can not initialize the static members of the class and I can get the reason. So the problem is in the `MotionDirection.cpp`, see the comments for the details about the compiler errors.

MotionDirection.h

```
#ifndef MOTION_DIRECTION
#define MOTION_DIRECTION

namespace game{
    class IntPosition;

    class MotionDirection {
        private:
        IntPosition* positionDisplacement;
        float angle;
        MotionDirection* returnDirection;

        public:
        MotionDirection( IntPosition* positionDisplacement, float angle );
        void setReturnDirection ( MotionDirection* returnDirection );

        IntPosition* getPositionDisplacement();
        float getAngle();
        MotionDirection* getReturnDirection();

        static MotionDirection* NONE;
        static MotionDirection* LEFT;
        static MotionDirection* RIGHT;
        static MotionDirection* UP;
        static MotionDirection* DOWN;

        static void initStatics();
    };
}

#endif
```

MotionDirection.cpp

```
#include "MotionDirection.h"
#include "IntPosition.h"

namespace game{
    MotionDirection::NONE = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 0, 0),   0.0f );
    // here I get an error:
    // MotionDirection.cpp:10:5: error: 'NONE' in 'class game::MotionDirection' does not name a type

    MotionDirection::MotionDirection( IntPosition* positionDisplacement, float angle ) {
        this->positionDisplacement = positionDisplacement;
        this->angle = angle;
    }

    void MotionDirection::setReturnDirection ( MotionDirection* returnDirection ) {
        this->returnDirection = returnDirection;
    }

    IntPosition* MotionDirection::getPositionDisplacement() {
        return positionDisplacement;
    }

    float MotionDirection::getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    MotionDirection* MotionDirection::getReturnDirection() {
        return returnDirection;
    }

    void MotionDirection::initStatics () {
        MotionDirection::NONE  = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 0, 0),   0.0f );
        MotionDirection::LEFT  = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition(-1, 0), 180.0f );
        MotionDirection::RIGHT = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 1, 0),   0.0f );
        MotionDirection::UP    = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 0,-1),  90.0f );
        MotionDirection::DOWN  = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 0, 1), 270.0f );
    }

    MotionDirection::initStatics();
    // or here I get an error:
    // MotionDirection.cpp:45:35: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token

}
```

P.S. This is Android-NDK project, I run compilation from the cygwin console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First error

Just replace

```
MotionDirection::NONE = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 0, 0),   0.0f );
```

with

```
MotionDirection* MotionDirection::NONE = new MotionDirection ( new IntPosition( 0, 0),   0.0f );
```

Note `MotionDirection*` type before name of the variable: you need to provide compiler with a type.

#### Second error

You can't put expressions out of function blocks. There are two ways to do this "right":

1.

- Make `initStatics()` return value.
- Add private static variable.
- Initialize new static variable by assigning value of `initStatics()` to it.

2.

- Add nested class.
- Write call to `initStatics()` in its constructor.
- Add private static variable of that nested class.

Comment: yep, this helped! And what about the second error with static method `initStatics`?

Comment: I didn't notice it at first, just remove that line, it's not needed.

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy you can't call static functions that way. Is that what you tried?

Comment: Why I can't call them this way? What is the proper way to call static method?

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy I updated answer with comments about the second error. There is no simple solution for it.